# Labeling a box in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, labels

As shown in the working example below, I have red box around all the boxes. I want to label the box but I couldn't manage to do it. I tried to use some of the ways in given in the tikz examples but I was also unsuccessful. Could anybody please help me with this ? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx, tikz, enumerate, amssymb, pgf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{caption}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}


\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols,automata}

\tikzset{
 >=stealth',
 punktchain/.style={
 rectangle, 
 rounded corners, 
% fill=black!10,
draw=black, very thick,
text width=10em, 
minimum height=3em, 
text centered, 
on chain},
 line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=8em,
      draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
      text width=10em, 
      minimum height=3.5em, 
      text centered, 
      on chain},
      every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
      decoration={brace},
      tuborg/.style={decorate},
      tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
      every rectangle node/.style={color=black,thick}
    }

  \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     [node distance=.5cm,
      start chain=going below,]
        \node[punktchain, join] (timing) {Timing Solver};
        \node[punktchain, join] (solver)      {Solver};
        \node[punktchain, join] (impl)      {SolverImpl};
        \node[punktchain, join] (stp) {STPSolver};
        \node[punktchain, join, ] (stpimpl) {STPSolverImpl};

        \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(solver.north), \p2=(impl.south) in
        ($(2.5, \y1)$) -- ($(2.5, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {*};

      \draw[red,thick,dashed] ($(timing.north west)+(-1,0.3)$)  rectangle    ($(stpimpl.south     east)+(1,-0.2)$); 


 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Where do the label should go?

Comment: Probably on top or below is the best place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the `current bounding box` to place a node containing the label:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx, tikz, enumerate, amssymb, pgf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{caption}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}


\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols,automata}

\tikzset{
 >=stealth',
 punktchain/.style={
 rectangle, 
 rounded corners, 
% fill=black!10,
draw=black, very thick,
text width=10em, 
minimum height=3em, 
text centered, 
on chain},
 line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=8em,
      draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
      text width=10em, 
      minimum height=3.5em, 
      text centered, 
      on chain},
      every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
      decoration={brace},
      tuborg/.style={decorate},
      tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
      every rectangle node/.style={color=black,thick}
    }

  \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     [node distance=.5cm,
      start chain=going below,]
        \node[punktchain, join] (timing) {Timing Solver};
        \node[punktchain, join] (solver)      {Solver};
        \node[punktchain, join] (impl)      {SolverImpl};
        \node[punktchain, join] (stp) {STPSolver};
        \node[punktchain, join, ] (stpimpl) {STPSolverImpl};

        \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(solver.north), \p2=(impl.south) in
        ($(2.5, \y1)$) -- ($(2.5, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {*};

      \draw[red,thick,dashed] ($(timing.north west)+(-1,0.3)$)  rectangle    ($(stpimpl.south     east)+(1,-0.2)$); 

      \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {Some Text};
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]